# Loading a XML file into a xmltype field with sqlLoader

Tags: xml, oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load a XML file into a XMLTYPE clob in oracle 11g. 
So far I came up with this control file:

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'stocknotify.xml'
append INTO TABLE order_input 
(
    xml LOBFILE(CONSTANT 'stocknotify.xml') TERMINATED BY EOF
)
```

This control file works pretty well, except that it load the XML file 7 times.
I guess this is because the XML file consists of 7 lines, however, I have no clue how to prevent sql loader from doing his and load the file only once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL*Loader suggestion:

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'stocknotify.xml'
append INTO TABLE order_input 
xmltype(XMLDATA)
(
    XMLDATA LOBFILE('stocknotify.xml') TERMINATED BY EOF
)
```